# Using jquery file upload with send method how to send javascript object in formData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery-file-upload with the send method. It works like a charm and files are correctly sent. Here is a bit of code to show what I do.

```
$form.fileupload(
  'send', 
  {
    files: filesList,
    formData: function() {  
        return [{name: 'people', value: people}];
    }
  }
)
```

But I try to send a javascript object such as and it's not well sent

```
var people = [
   {id: 1, firstName: 'Robert', age: '25'},
   {id: 2, firstName: 'Mohamed', age: '40'}
];
```

I can see in the headers that the object is not serialize.

[image: headers]

I think it's because the files are sent by the form and I am wondering if it's possible to "mix" form data with json data. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by1rybzn/2/) for this (you have to add at least one files to make it work).

Do you guys think I have to send all the data by form? Or there is a solution to send the files by the form and my js object by serialize it?

Comment: try JSON.stringify(people), it should return you a string, pass that string to your server.

On your server, encode it to an object again with whichever framework you are using (you can google PHP/ASP json parsing)

Comment: it does not work, the string is not correctly interpreted by jquery-file-upload. I see in the function _getFormData of jquery.fileupload.js that String type is not interpreted.

Comment: Mh, I'm not that familiar with jquery-file-upload so it was somewhat of a wild guess based on the unexpected `object Object` output. I don't see any arbitrary limitations in `_getFormData` (it just has a different way of getting the same result from a function, array or object), but I would suggest trying to pass simpler data to `send` first (like just an array with 1 or 2 `int` values, before trying more complicated things like a function or object.

Comment: I tested it. It works with simple object such as {id: 1, firstName: 'robert', age: 25}

Comment: Did you replace `var people = ..` with just that simple object, or the entire `return [{...}]` from your formData function?

Comment: the entire `return` like this :  `formData: {id: 5, name: 'Robert', age: '25'}`